# Android - Facebook wall post parameters

Tags: android, facebook

I am posting to a user's wall on Facebook. How can I add a link to the post next to the *like* and *comment* links, as seen on the illustration below. What is the parameter name I should include in my request?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I eventually did:

The link besides the *like* and *comment* is called "actions". To add it, you need to create an array of actions (actually, as I understand only one action is supported). For example:

```
JSONObject actions = new JSONObject();
actions.put("name","Get Your App");
actions.put("link", "Your app URL");

parameters.putString("actions", actions.toString());
```

Comment: Yep, this is the way to do that!

Comment: did you have to throw an exception ?

Comment: Are You referring to JSONObject? If so I surrounded it (and the actions.put) with a try/catch block.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) is list of all Post Fields.

`link` | The link attached to this post | Requires `access_token` | string containing the URL

Comment: I don't understand how to post a link at the point the arrow is pointing (In the attached pic)